ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.monitor'
I am trying to run BB84 protocol code on latest Qiskit version 1.0.2 and getting this error.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.monitor'

from qiskit import *
import numpy as np
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.monitor import job_monitor
%matplotlib inline
from tabulate import tabulate


How did you install qiskit?

That module has been removed since version 1.0.
On the Qiskit feature changes pages, there is this particular section:

The qiskit.tools.monitor submodule has been removed as it was tied to the legacy qiskit-ibmq-provider package, which is no longer supported (it also only supported BackendV1 interface and not the newer BackendV2 interface). There is no alternative provided for this functionality.

While this is called qiskit.tools.monitor, I'm guessing this is the same, and that qiskit.monitor was just a shortcut to this particular module.
